# error code ELIFECYCLE errno 1 error functions@ lint: `eslint .` while deploying firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to deploy my function to the firebase but when ever i execute

```
firebase deploy
```

i do get the error.

```
C:\Users\vimiv>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'touch-keeper'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\vimiv\functions
> eslint .

module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'wordwrap'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vimiv\functions\node_modules\optionator\lib\help.js:6:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vimiv\functions\node_modules\optionator\lib\help.js:247:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vimiv\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08- 
17T10_47_41_587Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

here is my index.js

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('DR/MELTING/{itemname}').onWrite(event => {
//const itemname = event.params.itemname;

console.log("Notificatiion Triggered Successfuly");
});
```

here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint .",
"serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
"shell": "firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.5",
"prelude-ls": "^1.1.2",
"word-wrap": "^1.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^4.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

And also i changed my firebase.json prefix command

Answer (score 2):

You need to install any dependency you may be using in your function. Run `npm install` inside your functions folder.

Comment: I done it. But still I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you update the post with your package.json and index functions file?

Comment: i have add index and package file codes.

Comment: Is wordwrap inside functions/node_modules dir? Also, it seems you're not using that module in your index after all...

Comment: yes word-wrap do present in functions/node_modules. yeah you were correct that is why i am confused right now.

Comment: i tried to deploy my function from the different system, it worked perfectly. but i don't know why it is throwing such error in my system alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `npm install -g word-wrap` and after `firebase deploy`.

Comment: I tried those. But still same error